# @Scene Builder version 21 --When using scenebuilder textfield in Debian 12 KDE and Gnome, Chinese cannot be input

Tags: scenebuilder

When using scenebuilder textfield in Debian 12 KDE and Gnome, Chinese cannot be input.

- Environment: Use fcitx5 input method.

Expected Behavior

- I hope to use scenebuilder to switch between Chinese input methods and display Chinese normally.

Current Behavior

- Currently using scenebuilder, the Chinese input method cannot be switched normally, nor can Chinese be displayed normally.

Steps to Reproduce

- Open the scenebuilder, add an "AnchorPane" panel, and add a "Label" control on the panel.
- At this time, if you input Chinese in the control, you cannot switch between the input method and the Chinese display.

My desktop environment:

- debian12+kde(wayland)+fcitx5+openJDK 17+SceneBuilder 21